# use function return as JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript

I got this js line:

```
var functest = function(){
    if (this.href === "undefined") { 
        return window.location 
    } else { 
        return this.href 
    }
};
```

Basically I want this `if` function to return the variable necesarry and assign it to functest.

This obviously is not working and returns the function as a string somehow. How should I do this?

Comment: You are making `functest` the function.  To prove this write the following code `functest();` this will call the above function and return either the href or the window.location

Comment: Question is: Why do you have a function at all?

Comment: You should use `window.location.href`, not just `window.location`

Comment: This is incorrect. `this.href === "undefined"` Drop the quotes `this.href === undefined`

Comment: @Felix don't want to rewrite the rest of the function around it to accommodate for this addition.

Comment: @cookiemonster, SnippetSpace probably wanted to use `typeof this.href === 'undefined'`

Comment: @zzzzBov: SnippedSpace would do better to not use that syntax for the very reason shown in the question. `this.href === undefined` is safer and more readable.

Comment: @cookiemonster, actually, `typeof this.href === 'undefined'` is the safer way, as `undefined` is a mutable variable name, which means that anyone could call something like `undefined = 'foo'` and break scripts left and right. Certainly it would be foolish to change the value of `undefined`, but it's possible.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Never seen it actually happen. Certainly even less possible now that we can't redefined the global `undefined`. But *many* times I've seen mistakes like the one above. And even if someone did do `var undefined = "foo";`, it would likely show up in multiple places, whereas an error like the one above could more easily go unnoticed. The `=== undefined` comparison is much safer and clearer.

Comment: @cookiemonster, I'm going to be hypocritical here, bear with me. Comments aren't the proper place for extended discussion, shoot me an email if you'd like to discuss this more. (begin hypocrisy) I hope you'll agree: when making portable code you need to write in a way that works in any environment. `typeof foo === 'undefined'` will work irrespective of where it's called, no matter the atrocities committed by other developers. That's what makes it "safer". A better option is to wrap code in an IIFE with a parameter of `undefined`, and check variables against the local `undefined` parameter.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Yep, I agree. An IIFE with a local `undefined` is a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the function to assign its return value:

```
var functest = (function () {
    if (this.href === 'undefined') {
        return window.location;
    } else {
        return this.href;
    }
}());//note the extra parenthesis to call the function
```

This particular function is probably better written as a single-line ternary assignment:

```
var functest = this.href === 'undefined' ? window.location : this.href;
```

Also, you probably wanted to check that `this.href === undefined` or `typeof this.href === 'undefined'`:

```
var functest = typeof this.href === 'undefined' ? window.location : this.href;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the function to be assigned to a variable that you can call when needed and then you want to assign the return value to a variable:

```
var functest = function(){if (this.href === "undefined") { return window.location } else { return this.href } };
var funcVal = functest();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with self-executing function like this :

```
var functest = (function () {
    if (this.href === "undefined") { return window.location } else { return this.href }
})();
```